# How to read every Integers in a line from a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

I have file that has n lines of Integers. I want to add each int in each line and print them (so I should print 3 int at the end, each one for a line).

I tried this but it will read and add all the Integers in the first loop.

```
scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
int n = scan.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
         sum += scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: So every line should be sum of current integer and all previous?

Comment: Yes, all previous Integers in the same line

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data in a `String` to replace the `input.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is caused by erroneous usage of loops and scans.
One of correct solutions also incorporates java 8 lambdas, with the assumption that the delimiter of the integers in the file is space(" "):

```
    Path path = Paths.get("your path");
    try{
        Files.lines(path)
                .map( line -> line.split(" "))
                .mapToInt( numbers -> Arrays.stream(numbers)
                   .reduce(0 , (sum, num) -> sum + Integer.parseInt(num), (first, second) -> first + second ))
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Tank you. but I should use something like BufferedReader or other Buffery things.

Comment: This condition was never mentioned before. But if you look at the implementation of Files.lines(), it uses the BufferedReader, so basically you can copy from there if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could do this too...

```
read = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
int n = read.nextInt(), j;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    String[] str;
    int t = read.nextInt();
    // First str will be ""(it reads the end of each line) 
    str = read.nextLine().split(" ");
    // Then it can read what we want
    str = read.nextLine().split(" ");
    for (j = 0; j < str.length; j++) 
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;                
}
```